# Autoit - Only require admin rights if statement is true

Tags: if-statement, admin, autoit

Is there a way to require admin in Autoit only if statement is true?

I tried

```
Global $a = 0
If $a == 1 Then
    #RequireAdmin
EndIf
```

But that doesn't seem to work, it still asks for Admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's no problem if there are more files:

```
$a = 1

If($a = 1) Then

Run(Run Script with #RequireAdmin)

Else

Run(Run Script without #RequireAdmin)

EndIf
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use this:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

If IsAdmin() Then
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "IsAdmin" & @CRLF & "Admin rights are detected.")
EndIf
```

If not isAdmin and your var = true then ...

Comment: This isn't quite the answer I was looking for. This is to get your script/program to know if it has admin rights but I wanted to know how you can get admin rights (#RequireAdmin) only if a statement is true, because it will ask for admin rights as soon as the program is opened, not once it checks the if statement for some reason.

Comment: Still don't get it. If you start your script, you can check whether the user who started the script has admin rights or not. During your script runs, you can do the same check. What ist missing? Also have a look here : https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/145697-_isuacadmin-check-admin-and-elevation-rights/?do=findComment&comment=1029937

Comment: Look at the code in my post, what I am having trouble is that I want my script to start WITHOUT admin rights, but if a statement is true, then half way through while the script is running, ask for admin rights so it HAS admin rights. My purpose for this is to check if this is the first time running the script, if so then ask for admin rights so it can setup a few things on your PC

Comment: I don't want the user to right click the program and click start with admin rights. This will be used with someone who doesnt know autoit, so I want the script to be automatic without the user having to do any advanced stuff

Comment: Yes, what I meant was. If your var is true, then you could restart your script with RunAs ... and everything is fine.

Comment: Oh I see, thats cool I think that's solved my problem, I will test it out. Thanks man

Comment: I am having trouble with the RunAs function. I just looked into it but I am not sure how I am able to runas administrator if I don't know the user's username and password for the computer. Is there a simple way to restart the program as admin on a users computer I have no info of?

Comment: Of course not. Either the user who starts the script is admin or you know the credentials and use them in RunAs or you force the user to start the script as admin by using RequireAdmin

Comment: You can run the script as really admin with psexec, but you already need to able to do that. You need the rights to elevate your rights.